# Sub Menu Item Command MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, menuitem

```
<MenuItem Header="Flag(s)" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LineItemFlags}" Command="{Binding AssignFollowupCommand}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlagName}">    
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

For the parent Item i mean menu item i have a command it's invoking i want to know how to setup command for Sub Menu item

Comment: My Problem is nothing with Item source Weather we give path or not it will still bind i want to give command for the sub items

Comment: Why don't you just nest the MenuItems and assing each one a command?
Example:
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="SubMenuItemStyle">
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlagName}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AssignFollowupCommand}" >
      <MenuItem Command="{Binding YourCommand}" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuItemStyle}"/>
    </MenuItem>
  </Grid>

Answer (score 3):

Rather than setting the ItemTemplate, set the ItemContainerStyle. Give it a style that sets the Header and Command properties of the menu item.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Recent Files" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding FileName}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Open}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Full example and description on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37848/WPF-Data-Bound-Menus).

Comment: Our base types are themed, so I needed to do this in addition:

`<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}"`